# PHP time interval of at least ten days

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

The idea is to query the users latest time stamp of their latest profile change. If it has been less than ten days when they try to update it they will be denied. No matter what I seem to do I cant get the 10 day difference logic correctly.  $stamp is is Y-m-d date format in the database.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$json=$_POST['user'];
$json=str_replace('\\','',$json);
$user=json_decode($json);
$pdo=new PDO('mysql://hostname=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
$update = $pdo->prepare("update  `accounts` set  stamp=CURDATE(),`title`='{$user->title}' ,`radio_hanlde`='{$user->radio_handle}' , `carrier`='{$user->carrier}' ,`hometown`='{$user->hometown}'  WHERE user_id='{$user->user_id}' AND DATE_DIFF(CURRDATE(),stamp) > 10");
$update->execute();
if ($update->rowCount() != 0 ){
     echo json_encode(array('success'=>'1','message'=>'Your profile has been updated successfully!'));} 
     else {echo json_encode(array('success'=>'0','message'=>'It has been less than ten days since your latest profile change. You will have to wait!'));}
?>
```

Comment: it should be a problem. Print out both the date to see if the values are correct or not..date_create($stamp[1]); specially this value

Comment: $stamp[0] returns "Array" , $stamp[1] returns " ". I dont get it. When I look in sql workbench it contains "2016-23-01" and field is a not-null date.

Comment: What can I possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: here's my query $query=$pdo->query("Select stamp FROM channel1_db.accounts where user_id='{$user->user_id}'");    
 $stam=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: you are doing it wrong @Robert ... iterate over the stamp and take a variable..in the foreach loop assign the value..and use that variable for comparison

Comment: I'm so new to php its ridiculous.  The php script is for my Android app which is my forte. I was expecting a single value to be returned with my query. I asked it for a single column from a specific row. My understanding of php is that it returns a multi-layered array regardless.  So $stamp[1] would be the 2nd row.  There are no other layers.  Can you give me an example of what you mean with the foreach loop?

Comment: You don't need two queries here. You only need an UPDATE

Comment: well I query the last time they updated theyre profile i.e. "stamp" from "accounts"...if it's been more than ten days I update the profile and stamp to 'now' and the posted information from the user inside client android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's mysqli and PDO APIs have functions for detecting whether an UPDATE affected any rows (mysqli_affected_rows() and PDOStatement::rowCount(), respectively), so you can pretty much throw away all of your code.

All you need to do is UPDATE all rows for the given user that match the criteria, e.g.:

```
UPDATE accounts
   SET stamp = '$stamp'
     , title = '{$user->title}' 
     , radio_hanlde [SIC] ='{$user->radio_handle}' 
     , carrier  = '{$user->carrier}' 
     , hometown = '{$user->hometown}'
 WHERE user_id  = '{$user->user_id}'
   AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),stamp) > 10;
```

If PDOStatement::rowCount() returns a value other than 0, print message 1 otherwise print message 2.

As per the following example, assembled by the OP...

```
$pdo->exec("
UPDATE accounts 
   SET stamp = '$stamp'
     , title = '{$user->title}'
     , radio_hanlde ='{$user->radio_handle}'
     , carrier = '{$user->carrier}'
     , hometown = '{$user->hometown}' 
 WHERE user_id = '{$user->user_id}' 
   AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),stamp) > 10
 "); 

if (PDOStatement::rowCount() < 1 ){
     echo json_encode(array('success'=>'0','message'=>'It has been less than ten days since your latest profile change. You will have to wait!'));
 } else {
     echo json_encode(array('success'=>'1','message'=>'Your profile has been updated successfully!'));
 }
```

Comment: @RobertGoodrick That looks like the right kind of thing, but see prepared statements.

Comment: Okay Stawberry! Thats what i'm talking about! Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah It's having issues with if (PDOStatement::rowCount() > 0 ){
 echo json_encode(array('success'=>'0','message'=>'It has been less than ten days since your latest profile change. You will have to wait!'));
 }else{
 echo json_encode(array('success'=>'1','message'=>'Your profile has been updated successfully!'));
 }

Comment: Not sure what those might be - nor why "< 1" would work if "> 0" doesn't - but I'm not much of a PHP coder

Comment: I'm not either. I had one set up the php end of my application and then he disappeared.  But i've slowly added some functions and additions after the fact. And yes > 0 would be more appropriate. Problem is I'm not receiving the else echo in either case

Comment: okay i'm using a prepared update statement and so able to use rowcount() afterwards and it works great. Problem is now the AND condition is never true even though stamp is more than 10 days in the past....

Comment: the column is a date() ...any ideas why the date_diff($date, $date2) > 10 wouldnt like this?

Comment: This is driving me up the wall...now i'm trying this AND new DateTime(curdate()) > new DateTime(stamp) condition and it aways results in count() of 0

Comment: @RobertGoodrick I think I mistyped the DATEDIFF function (was DATE_DIFF!!).

Comment: Yeah I actually caught that early.  I'll edit my code portion in the original question to show my current php. Still haven't solved the issue.  Rows affected is always 0 because the date difference is never over ten.

Comment: Really? It seems worse now then it was before (`DATE_DIFF(CURRDATE`). And can we please have some formatting

Comment: SO..wasnt accessing $stamp correctly. Here is what Ive figured out to do so. $stamp = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$shifted=array_shift($stamp); and then $shifted['stamp'] contains the value :)

Comment: Great. So, either edit my question and accept it, or add an answer below and accept that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Function strtotime returns timestamp in seconds, so you can get diff in seconds very simple like this

```
$secs = strtotime('now') - strtotime($stamp);
$days = $secs / 60 / 60 / 24;
if($days <= 10) {
    ..your code...
}
```

Comment: From review, thanks for your answer on SO, to improve your answer consider to not only provide code but also some description about why and what your code does. Example what is the `strtotime` function ecc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $today=date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
 $date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
 $diff=date_diff($today,$date2);

if($diff<10){
  echo "Your alert";
}
```

Comment: i'm trying this date_diff(date1, date2) call but I seem to have some issue with the date object. I've been racking my brain on this for days and cant seem to see the error.

Comment: Danyal could you perhaps review my edited code post to see what you think might be going on to where $wait is returning 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $querydata="SELECT CURDATE()";
                                 $result_data= mysqli_query($link, $querydata);
                                  $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result_data)[0];
                                $intervaloTempo = gmdate("d:H:i:s", time() + (10 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Use this for your query

```
 "(().data=\"".$data."\" and ()>=\"".$intervaloTempo."\"" )"

                                    $query = sprintf("select stamp from accounts where user_id='{$user->user_id}, mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['cliente_id']));
                                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                                    if (!$result) {
                                        die("Query error: " . mysqli_error($link));
                                        //con_close();
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function to get current time in seconds (Unix timestamp) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert any date format to timestamp. Here is refactored code of your example:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$messages = [
    'error_invalid_json' => 'Error. Invalid json',
    'error_account_not_found' => 'Error. Account is not found',
    'success' => 'Your profile has been updated successfully!',
    'wait_1_day' => 'It has been less than ten days since your latest profile change. You must wait until tomorrow!',
    'wait_n_days' => 'It has been less than ten days since your latest profile change. You have %s more to go!',
];

function message($message, $success = true)
{
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => ($success) ? 1 : 0,
        'message' => $message,
    ]);

    exit;
}

// get and validate incoming data
$json = $_POST['user'];
$json = str_replace('\\', '', $json);
if (empty($json)) {
    message($messages['error_invalid_json'], false);
}
try {
    $user = json_decode($json);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    message($messages['error_invalid_json'], false);
}
if (empty($user->user_id)) {
    message($messages['error_invalid_json'], false);
}

// find last modified date
$pdo = new PDO('mysql://mydb', 'a_user', 'password');
$query = $pdo->query("Select stamp FROM accounts WHERE user_id='{$user->user_id}' LIMIT 1");
$stamp = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (empty($stamp)) {
    message($messages['error_account_not_found']);
}

// calculcate when user is allowed to change profile
$daysShouldPassBeforeEdit = 10;
$allowEditAfter = ($stamp[1]) ? strtotime($stamp[1]) + $daysShouldPassBeforeEdit * 86400 : time(); // if empty `stamp` then user have not edited and allow to edit now

if (time() < $allowEditAfter) {
    $daysLeftBeforeAllowEdit = ceil(($allowEditAfter - time()) / 86400);

    if ($daysLeftBeforeAllowEdit == 1) {
        message($messages['wait_1_day'], false);
    } else {
        message(sprintf($messages['wait_n_days'], $daysLeftBeforeAllowEdit), false);
    }
}

// save changes
$stamp = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "update  `accounts` set  stamp='$stamp',`title`='{$user->title}' ,`radio_hanlde`='{$user->radio_handle}' , `carrier`='{$user->carrier}' ,`hometown`='{$user->hometown}'  where user_id='{$user->user_id}'";
$pdo->exec($sql);
message($messages['success']);
```

Comment: okay. Stupid question I know but please help me with this last deal. Okay with Limit 1 stamp[0] finally returns the value i'm looking for in another array as {"stamp":"2016-01-29"}.  how to simply extract the date?  That's all I need now.  $stamp[0]->stamp..?????????

Comment: `$stamp[0]['stamp']`